# How can I specify the Content Mode of a UIButton in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistoryboard

I've run into a problem with `UIButton`s in Stack Views. The image that the buttons are set to get squished whenever there's not enough vertical space for them, such as when the phone is in horizontal orientation, or on a small device.

I did find a solution, by running: `button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` in `viewDidLoad()` but it seems like the wrong way to do it.

I assume that the best way to do this would be within Storyboard. First of all, is this the best way? Second of all, how would I do it? (I'm still very new to iOS development)

I have tried using [image: this dropdown menu] in the attributes inspector, but that doesn't seem to have done anything. Maybe I'm missing a step.

Comment: What do you mean by "to get squished"?  You mean to get squashed?

Comment: [Like this](https://imgur.com/a/ZYuvOST)

Answer (score 0):

## Storyboard vs Code

There are people that prefer code over storyboard. There are people that prefer storyboard over code. There is no wrong or right way since both ways are correct. Do whatever you think is better and/or easier.

## Setting the Content Mode through the Storyboard

I don't think this is possible. I think the **Content Mode** you were trying to set is the Content Mode of the button you had selected. I don't think there is another Content Mode dropdown for the embedded `UIImageView` in the `UIButton`. Your best bet would be to set the `.imageView.contentMode` through code like you already did.